# Compile results from all test suites in extent report

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, extentreports

The extent report is only reporting the last test suite that has been run.

I have set up selenium tests with 10 different suits that is run in order. The problem is that the Extent Report is only logging the results of the last suite. I have tried different ways of implementing the report to compile all of the results.

The code structure: 
BaseSetUp Class - initialze the driver (OneTimeSetUp, SetUp, TearDown, OnetimeTearDown)

Generalmethod calls - inherits from BaseSetUp

PageObject Page - get all Page Objects

TestSuits - Inherits from General methods.

I have the report in the BaseSetUp class like this:

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {

        try
        {
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
            var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(dir + "\\Test_Execution_Reports" + "\\Automation_Report" + ".html");
            extent.AddSystemInfo("Environment", "Xylect AT");
            extent.AddSystemInfo("User Name", "Lucas");
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
       }}



 [SetUp]
    public void BeforeTest()
    {
        try
        {
            _test = extent.CreateTest(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }


    [TearDown]
    public void AfterTest()
    {
        try
        {
            var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
            var stacktrace = "" + TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace + "";
            var errorMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;
            Status logstatus;
            switch (status)
            {
                case TestStatus.Failed:
                    logstatus = Status.Fail;
                    string screenShotPath = Capture(driver, TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
                    _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus + " – " + errorMessage);
                    _test.Log(logstatus, "Snapshot below: " + _test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath));

                    break;
                case TestStatus.Skipped:
                    logstatus = Status.Skip;
                    _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus);
                    break;
                default:
                    logstatus = Status.Pass;
                    _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus);
                    break;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }

   [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {

        try
        {

            //zip();
            //Email();
            extent.Flush();
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw (e);
        }

    }
```

Ive seen a couple of methods where the prevous report is added to the "new" created one, but i did not get this to work.

Example of a testcase in one of the testsuites

```
        [TestCase(TestName = "01_LogIn"), Order(1)]
    public void LogIn()
    {
        LogIn();
        string loginAssert = HomePage.expLoginName.Text;
        Assert.IsTrue(loginAssert.Contains("Hi, " + username + ""), "Login falied");

    }
```

Any ideas on how i should move forward?

Running extent report V4

Comment: does OneTimeSetUp run everytime a new suite begin to run? then you have this problem

Comment: Yes it does. how should it then be?

Comment: I need more info on how suites are setup? How are you triggering the test run - testng runner?or main method.? extent report object creation should be happening only once throughout your execution. see if you can devise a logic to set it up only once and pass the report to rest of the suites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just follow this link. I hope it solves your problem.

You must create 3 classes.

```
BaseFixture.cs
ExtentManager.cs
ExtentTestManager.cs
```

After that, you can initialize the BaseFixture in every test class.

```
[TestFixture, Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
    public class MemberLogInOut : BaseFixture
```

https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-csharp/tree/master/ExtentReports/ExtentReports.Tests/Parallel

Comment: Thanks! I will try the setup as described in the link. However im getting an error in the ExtentManager class on the htlm.Configuration() method. Where is this method from?

Comment: Hi, Lucas.
sorry I didn't understand what you said. Anyway is it possible to share your code here?. I will try. which ExtentReports version are you using?

Comment: got it to work now.. I cant really share the code except the code provided from extent report, due to the company. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice... Good job.